# Catching only one group out of two on both sides of |

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to catch something inside double or single quotes, logically, I do this:

```
>>> re.match( '"(\d+)"|\'(\d+)\'', "'123'" ).groups()
(None, '123')
```

But for some reason two groups are returned, why?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your regex contains two groups and `groups()` returns "*a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern*" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.groups).

Comment: I thought only matched groups are returned, first one didn't. How can I achieve my goal then?

Comment: @VasylDemianov `re.match( '(["\'])(\d+)\\1', "'123'" ).group(2)` might work. Disclaimer: I don't know Python.

Comment: you are right, it will in this very case, but it will not if the string I am trying to match is `'"123"'`.

Comment: @VasylDemianov I tried it in https://repl.it/languages/python3 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = '..."123"...'
s2 = "...'123'..."
s3 = """...'123"..."""

>>> re.findall(r'(\'\d+\'|"\d+")', s1)
['"123"']

>>> re.findall(r'(\'\d+\'|"\d+")', s2)
["'123'"]

>>> re.findall(r'(\'\d+\'|"\d+")', s3)
[]
```

Comment: Yeah, this will work and I can remove quotes afterwards, but I am sure there must be a way to achieve this using regex.

Comment: No, not a regex, use comprehension. If you use PyPi regex module you can use a branch reset though.